# Disappearing files from server and records from database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1

I know that's a silly question, but I've tried everything.

Project that I'm working on was maintained by many people, so it's very buggy. 
Once a time, photos with random generated names are disppearing from server. Last days, db records disappear to, but mostly without any relation with other.

I've search in files for commands

```
unset()
```

and doctrine

```
delete()
```

and nothing strange found. Do you have any ideas how could it happen? Maybe it's the server problem, not the code?

Comment: Try to log all db queries.

Comment: I had the same problem on a server. The hosting company was rolling back each morning without notifying. Probably a bad HDD or wrong argument in backup command.

Comment: Strange situation but a nightmare for a developer for sure. I would recommend to ask server support guys to take a deep look in to this situation and tighten up the security bridge if there is any loopholes.

Comment: or... maybe some plain sql "DELETE FROM ...". Unlinkely, but still worth checking.

Comment: ok, thanks I will ask them

Comment: you can look for unlink() too